# Syntax Error? When parsing XML value

Tags: javascript, xml

I don't know if I'm having a syntax error but the compiler is giving me

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating
>   'xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("icon")[count].childNodes')

Its me giving me this problem when im parsing the `XML` from my `server`, my actual javascript code is like this

```
var xmlDoc = Obj.responseXML;
var count = 0;
if(xmlDoc){
    while(count <= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").length){
    document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML += "<div class='item'><img class='content' src='" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("icon")[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/\s+$/g,' ') +"' /></div>";
    count++;
    }
       }else{
           alert("Unable to parse!");
       }
```

and my XML goes like this.

```
<feed>
<item>
<title>Given Title</title>
<icon>
http://i178.photobucket.com/albums/w255/ace003_album/Logo-ETC-RGB-e1353503652739.jpg
</icon>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</feed>
```

i just want to parse the image link and to show it.
DOM parser

```
 var url = "http://myURL.com/document.xml";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          Obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          Obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        Obj.open("POST",url,false);
        Obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Obj.send();
```

Comment: check what `i` is, what is probably happening is you are trying to access an icon element that doesn't exist in the node list.

Comment: so sorry, I dont know whats that :)

Comment: @Ace Munim Give a look http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/xpath-example.html and https://npmjs.org/package/xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3hGs/)

Firstly, you're while loop condition should be just `<` not `<=`. By using the latter, the loop is running one too many times, causing the error because the index is out of bounds.

Secondly, in the while loop you're getting the `icon` elements based on the `count` from the root of the document. The `icon`'s are children of each `item` so you should retrieve the `icon` relative to the `item` by using `item.getElementsByTagName('icon')[0]` not `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('icon')[count]`.

Not related to the problem but building HTML as strings like that is undesirable. Creating the elements and inserting them into the DOM would be better because you don't need to handle any escaping. Also, store a reference to `flow` before the while, instead of finding it on each iteration.

```
var div;
var img;
var flow = document.getElementById('flow');
var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

while(count < items.length){
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'item';

    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.className = 'content';
    img.src = items[count].getElementsByTagName("icon")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/\s+$/g,' ');

    div.appendChild(img);
    flow.appendChild(div);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: i did change and all, and sorry the variable `i` with `count` was a typo, and also I've implemented the method you told me as it is much better in creating element. But still im having the same error. Is there any way to check whether I'm getting the proper XML?

Comment: yup it is, added the DOM parser in the question.

Comment: im getting the full XML from my site with the `Obj.responseXML`

Comment: See my edit. There's a couple of problems. Also see the demo (you don't need the DOMParser that I have in the fiddle but it's needed for the demo).